# MySQL: How to make sure always selects unique records

Tags: python, mysql

I am running a Python Script that spawns several processes. The process calls a method that itself runs a `SELECT` query every time against a certain condition and fetches N records. The issue I am facing that every process is spawned on almost same time and `SELECT` is executed same time too thus many processes fetch same records against SELECTs

I want to know whether there is any way to select unique records? I know about `Order by Rand()` but it seems costly.

Table Schema given below:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| url         | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| source_file | varchar(255) | NO   |     |                   |                |
| proxy_url   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| duration    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| status      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: We don't know enough about the table in question. For example, does it contain a numeric ID? If yes, is the ID ascending by exactly one from row to row, or are there holes? Could you show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_in_question>`? By the way, you are right that `ORDER BY RAND()` is very costly. It sorts the complete table before selecting. If you have only 100 rows, you don't need to think about it, but if you have one million rows, the performance penalty will be drastic (a.k.a. unusable).

Comment: @Binarus The question updated.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Your script spawns multiple processes virtually concurrently, each executing a select query. This would make the SELECTs also concurrent. You want code that guarantees that the result set returned from each select is unique across all result sets? I don't see how such a scenario can possibly be guaranteed. The SELECT in each process would have to have knowledge of the SELECT in every other one AND know what the result set is. How is that even possible? Seems to me it would be best to write something that scans the result sets and generate uniqueness.

Comment: @DavidJenkins Yes you are right. This is why I am asking how could it be done either at DB level or application level.

Comment: An additional question: You said that the records selected by each process should be unique. But you also mentioned `ORDER BY RAND()` which does not provide uniqueness; the randomization of the sort order just provides a certain *probability* (as the term "RAND" already implies) that the records selected will be unique. So it is not clear to me if you really need the uniqueness in an absolute sense or if you would be happy if the different processes would select different records in *most* cases. Depending on the answer, different solutions might be appropriate.

Comment: How about having one process as producer that will select as many records as needed periodically and put them in the queue, while other processes consume from that queue?

Comment: @matino OK even if I put in the queue, how will I make sure other processes will always get unique records?

Comment: @Volatil3 - that's basically how the queues work, each consumer can get only one event. So you actually just need to make sure that the producer doesn't enqueue duplicates (e.g. storing an ID and always selecting records with ID greater than the stored one). Checkout this website to make things more clear: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be done at the application level either before the SELECTs are executed or after the result sets are returned. I would definitely opt for before the selects are made. Say there are 5 processes spawned and each one returns a result set of 10 rows. You could create 5 lists of 10 numbers and pass one to each process. Here's how I would do it. (this assumes a scenario in which the primary key is sequential, starts with 0, and no records are ever removed from the table):

First, the main script executes a query to get a count of the records in the table. Say this returns 10000. I would then do something like this:

```
from random import shuffle

process_count = 5
need = 10
list_of_lists = []

values = list(range(10000))
shuffle(values)

for i in range(process_count):
    start = i * need
    m = values[start:start+10]
    list_of_lists.append(m)
```

or you could bypass the loop and use a list comprehension:

```
list_of_lists = [ values[i*need:i*need+10] for i in range(process_count)]
```

list_of_lists now contains 5 lists of 10 effectively random numbers between 0 and the size of the table. At this point, iterate over list_of_lists and dish the lists out to the spawned processes. In each spawned process, the list is used to generate a SELECT from TABLE where ID IN () statement.

+++++++++++edit++++++++++++++++++

The fact that records are periodically removed presents a couple of problems. First, You cannot simply do a count on the table because since there are gaps, the max id will be greater than the table count. You could simply return all the id values, shuffle them, and create the individual lists. That can be expensive and impractical as the tables gets large. 
 You can get around this by sending an initial query that does something like this:

```
select max(id) from <tablename>;
```

You can then generate the list like this:

```
values = list(range(max_id_value + 1))
```

At this point you can do this: Say you need 10 rows returned from each spawned process. If you send each a list of 10 numbers, a process will send less than 10 if it is send a number that does not correspond to an id. One way around this is to send a list of say 30 values to each process. Then in the select query you could add LIMIT 10. The number you send would depend on how sparse the list of ids is.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: The processed records are being deleted periodically

Comment: If records are deleted and the primary keys are not sequential, your initial query could return all the primary keys as a result set. That set could be converted to a list and shuffled. Then proceed with the for loop as above. Mind you, the larger the table, the greater the performance hit. If it is large enough it could be unworkable.

Comment: @DeanSong Can you elaborate further? Are you responding to the solution of David?

Comment: No, it is general solution to retrieve unique elements. Have you check  document of numpy.unique? It calculate unique element int the array.Invoke  this function on your records, then it is done.

Comment: @DeanSong I am already using `numpy.shuffle`, the issue is, when the source (The SELECT QUERY) is picking same set of records across threads then how can I bring uniqueness?

Comment: @DeanSong Also, the list have unique records, the IDs, the thing is how to make sure two processes not picking the same record?